# libgdx how to get image to take up the whole screen?

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, render, sizing

I have this image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucafS.jpg) and am trying to make it take up the whole screen.
Heres my code

```
static Texture img;
static Sprite sprite;
public static void load(){

    img = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/stick.PNG"));
    //libgdx scales it , it wont mess up
    img.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    sprite = new Sprite(img);
    sprite.flip(false, true);
    sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

The output still doesnt show the stick figure taking up the whole screen.
Output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGTfV.jpg

Am i going about this the wrong way? I thought by setting the sprite(the object rendering the image to the screen) to the size of the screen, the image should take up the whole screen as well.

Comment: How are you setting your projection matrix on the sprite batch? It will depend on how you're doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    batch.draw(sprite.getTexture(), x, y, sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thx but whats x and y? I ended up not having to use those arguments

Comment: This will only work if you Sprite is the same dimensions as your camera viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Set the bound of the image.

```
        Image backgroundImage = new Image(Assets.loadTexture("wood.jpg"));
        backgroundImage.setBounds(0,0,screenWidth, screenHeight);
        backgroundImage.setOrigin(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2);
```

See image is now full screen

[image]